# Oracle XE and Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle11g, oracle-xe

Is it possible to install both Oracle XE and Oracle 11g in my machine? What is the difference between the two? I want to connect to Oracle using Access. Does this require Oracle 11g or can I also use Oracle XE?

Comment: I think Oracle XE is based on Oracle 10g. I'm not sure if the two can cohabitate peacefully.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to install as many (vaguely recent) versions of Oracle as you would like so long as you install them in separate Oracle Homes.  There can be a bit of complexity in having multiple versions of Oracle installed because each Oracle Home will have a separate client installation with separate configuration files by default (though you can centralize some of that with appropriate environment variables).  That can cause a bit of confusion if you're using the "wrong" client where, for example, you haven't configured a connection to a particular database.

Oracle XE is a free product that has various limits that make it sufficient for a smaller system (4 GB of user data, 1 GB of RAM, 1 CPU core if memory serves).  Oracle 11g is a family of different database products that Oracle sells (enterprise, standard, and standard edition one).  The feature difference between 10g and 11g is incremental-- probably nothing to be terribly concerned with if you're just building a simple system with an Access front end.

You should be able to connect to essentially any version of Oracle using Access by configuring an appropriate ODBC connection.  During the installation process, you will want to ensure that the Oracle ODBC driver is installed for whatever database(s) you use-- that's probably not in the default install.

Comment: The specs you give for Oracle XE seem to match up suspiciously well with the specs for SQL Server Express.

Comment: @David - Funny how the marketing departments manage that, isn't it?